# ES6 Proxy#apply for objects?

Tags: proxy, ecmascript-6

What I'm trying to create is a callable object. I was thinking with an ES6 `Proxy` it is possible, or at least the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/apply) doesn't mention that this shouldn't be possible (but the example only shows how to create a `Proxy` for a function):

```
const object = { foo: 'bar' }

const callableProxy = new Proxy(object, {
  apply(target, self, args) {
    console.log('Yay!')
  }
})

callableProxy()
```

But this just throws `TypeError: callableProxy is not a function` on both node and chrome. What is the situation here? Is this by design? If it is, why on earth would the standard exclude this option?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Yes, this is by design: a proxy is only callable when also its target is callable, and this callability never changes. This e.g. makes the proxy still work when the `apply` handler is changed or deleted (or changed to the default `Reflect` implementation)